# folder sharing error in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sharing

```
net usershare' returned error 255: [2024/03/31 13:47:04,  0] 
../../lib/util/debug.c:1100(reopen_one_log)
  reopen_one_log: Unable to open new log file 'PUBLIC/log.net': 
 No such file or directory
net usershare add: share name /media/user/e/public 
contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)
```

Comment: " share name /media/user/e/public contains invalid characters (any of %<>*?|/\+=;:",)" seems pretty clear to me? when using 2+ OS filenames and directories can ONLY have a set of characters that ALL support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to SAMBA share a folder always gives errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462387/trying-to-samba-share-a-folder-always-gives-errors)